# Extending vs Re-instantiating

Tags: oop

I'm wondering which of the following two methods would be more efficient, or if it doesn't actually matter which route you take as the overhead is minuscule.

Essentially, is it better to instantiate a class (for example, 'Db') that you know is going to be used often in a parent class and simply extend the parent class whenever you want to use 'Db', or is it better to instantiate 'Db' separately in the constructor of the classes you want to use it.

Obviously the best route to take in terms of avoiding duplicate code would be to instantiate it in a parent class but just out of curiosity I was wondering if anyone has any insight into how significant/insignificant the effect on the server is for these two routes.

**Route 1:**

```
// Parent
class template {

    public function __construct() {

        $this->db = new Db();

    }

}

// Child
class login extends template {

    public function __construct() {

        // Has access to $this->db

    }

}
```

**Route 2:**

```
class login {

    public function __construct() {

        $this->db = new Db();

    }

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using dynamic class variables is very bad practice. Whichever route you choose (and the choice is a fundamental OOP design choice) you **must** declare the `db` variable as a class field. The the first case that would be at least a protected field.

Comment: It is better to receive the `Db` object as an argument in the constructor. It is more flexible and testable.

Comment: The structural pattern @axiac is talking about, is called Dependency Injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't matter performance wise.

If you extend the template  class, you still have to instantiate the child class, which in turn will call the constructor of the parent implicitly. This means that in both cases, the DB class will be instantiated. Even worse, the extended class will probably be a little bit slower because it has the added overhead of an extra function call (that of the parent construct  method).

That being said I strongly recommend to read up on composition over inheritance. Parent child relations are there to enforce an "is a" relationship. If you start extending the same class simply for performance reasons, chances are you are going to shoot yourself in the foot later on. It is simply unexpected behavior for most programmers to have unrelated classes extend from the same parent.